# How do I find the kernel and range of a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

For example: $T: P_2 \to P_5$ given by $T(p(x)) = x^3(p(x))$

How would I find the kernel and range for this?

All I know is that $\dim(\ker T)+ \dim(\operatorname{image}T)= \dim(p_2)$.

Therefore, $\dim(\ker T)+ \dim(\operatorname{image}T)=3$?

Also, how do I represent T by a matrix with respect to bases for the domain and codomain?

Any help at all is appreciated, as I really have absolutely no idea what I am doing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

For your specific problem, you can find by inspection that the kernel is just 0 (the only polynomial that gives 0 when multiplied by $x^3$ is just 0) and the image is all the 5th-degree polynomials with no quadratic, linear, or constant terms (as everything has just been multiplied by $x^3$ and there can be no terms with degree less than 2 because of that).

However, in general, we can proceed this way: your linear transformation can be represented as a matrix:

$\left[ \begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix} \right]$

To find the kernel, row reduce this matrix as augmented with the identity, and look for all the zero rows:
$\left[ \begin{array}{cccccc|ccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array} \right]$

Conveniently, it is already row-reduced. So the kernel has no basis and therefore is trivial. If it did have a basis, the basis vectors would be the entries on the *right* matrix that corresponded to zero rows on the *left* matrix (remember that the kernel is expressed in terms of the domain space, not the range space).

I *believe* that to find a basis of the image, you look for all the *nonzero* rows after row reduction, but I forgot that part. (It seems to work in this case, however, as $\{x^3, x^4, x^5\}$ is indeed a basis for the image.)

Comment: Ok, I used another problem because I didn't want to cheat myself out of finding out how to do it. . . but the problem in my HW is T:P2- - >P4 given by T(p(x)) = x^2(P(x)) so I guess kerT is still 0 then. . . but I am still confused about how to find the range. . . is the basis of the image analogous to the range?

Comment: Oh, by "image" I mean "range". They're used interchangeably.

Comment: You are correct in saying that the kernel of T is still 0 in your case. The range is slightly different - just shift the exponents in the answer above down by 1.